# Wave Modifer - speed and width convertion

Tags: animation, modifiers

I have been trying to retrieve the bpm to add a pulse sound on a video. 
My wave modifier is at a fixed 
speed of 0.103147 | width 1.77972 m

How the speed value of the wave modifier could be adjusted to time? (which is the opposite but could be useful if i reiterate this idea..)

The value of speed in the wave modifier in the manual says speed per frame, so I would assume 1 would mean one wave per frame.  it seems to work but also width is affecting i'm not what to test anymore that's why i thought one of you might be of help.

Thank You!